# Can you gift games to yourself?

Tags: steam

It's the holiday season, and the steam sale just started, and I have the urge to buy many many games as gifts, BUT, I am not certain that people are going to want those games, and I might want them for myself if no one else desires said game.

Is it possible, if you have a gift copy of a game already bought, to give that gift to yourself?

Comment: Gifting things to yourself is part of my [master strategy for Steam sales](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/steam-sale-tricks/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of 4th of May, 2017, this is not possible anymore. You can either purchase the game for yourself, adding it directly to your library, or send it to a friend, who can either accept it, adding it to their library, or refund the game, refunding your money.

Here is the [official blog post](http://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1301948399254001159) explaining the change.

Comment: Such a miserable change, and has discouraged me from buying this summer sale. I really enjoyed being able to buy 3 or 4 copies of a game I love, so that I can gift them at a later date: To people who may not even be on my friends list as of this moment.

Comment: The drawback of this change is that you can no longer buy games as gifts on a sale, and if you never played it, you could sell it to someone you know. Now you have to commit to buying it to yourself. – A benefit of this change is that if no one wants your gift, you will not pay for the gift, and if you are unable to gift it to the person you want to give it to, you will again not pay for the gift.

Answer (score 30):

## Yes!

Games you buy as a gift [can be stored](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#gifts-delayed) in your [*gift inventory*](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#gifts-sent). From there, you get the choice to either *gift them* to someone via e-mail or to a Steam friend, or [add them to your library](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#expire).

Simply choose the *"Add to my game library ..."* option instead of *"Send gift ..."* in your Steam inventory.

Comment: You're too fast.

Comment: @3ventic I just want that tag badge.

Comment: This *does not work* for fourpacks if you own that specific game already. It was *impossible* to buy the fourpack for Demigod because I owned it already...

Comment: @Arperum Well, packages are different in a lot of ways. I'm obviously just talking about single game licenses. Some packages work, some don't - fourpacks notoriously *don't*.

Comment: What if I choose "Send gift..." and send it to my own mail?